# colors of trading objects in dwarf fortress

Tags: dwarf-fortress

I got goods to be traded on the trade depot. With help of trader started the trade.
on the trading screen the goods i have were in brown colored text (except 2).

what does these color mean?

From my observation in this case the cages were the white ones. any particular reason?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The brown means it's something that was made or decorated in your fortress, and counts towards your "exported wealth" (which can affect how likely such things as seiges or wandering titans are).

The white means that it was something that was NOT made or decorated in your fortress (in this case, the cages were either purchased or stolen from the elves), and thus has no effect on the "exported wealth" count.

Comment: Yes I had bought it from elves.